# Install a certificate on a web server

Tags: ssl, web-server, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

This is a noob question, I know.

I have a web server on an Ubuntu 16.04. I'd like to install a certificate on it so that I can secure it using Cloudflare SSL. Everything I've found online has web server-specific instructions, but I'm not sure what software I'm using. The code I'm using is [this, it's on GitHub.](https://github.com/timberline-secondary/hackerspace) I've followed all the instructions there to get this server running and accessible. My server runs on AWS.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Note: I'm using Django if that helps.

Comment: If you use Cloudflare, then you don't even need a certificate on your AWS, https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-End-to-end-HTTPS-with-Cloudflare-Part-3-SSL-options#h_4e0d1a7c-eb71-4204-9e22-9d3ef9ef7fef If you do want a server side certificate, you are now using Django development server https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ which is not supposed to be used for any production environment.

Comment: I found myself having to setup TLS on someone's web app handling sensitive data also written in python. While it wasn't Django, I eventually look into using Nginx as a proxy. You would install the certificates for Nginx, and then configure it as a proxy for your web app. I would start there... I then stepped out of the Nginx rabbit hole, and occasionally wonder what it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Example configuration:

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pythonProject

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.cert-only.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:!DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/pythonProject/MTurk/pythonProject.sock;
    }
}
```

Then copy the certificates to `/etc/nginx/ssl` and test:

`nginx -t`

And restart Nginx: `sysctl restart nginx`